# Mininet / python cannot assign requested adress [Errno 99]

Tags: python, networking, mininet

I am using the host.cmd() command of mininet to execute a script that does some networking:

```
print h1.cmd('cd ../src/; sudo ./script.py -r TCM -i h1-eth0 -a fd07::1 &> ../mininet/test.txt &')
```

The Problem is that this script cannot assign the network adress fd07::14! I also tried some other addresses, even the localhost is not working.

But when I run the exact same command directly in the mininet CLI it works. So I think there is some context problem? Does somebody know how to solve it?